# Redirect to a PHP file on a HTML button click with some data being sent via POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to redirect to a PHP file when a button on my initial screen is pressed.

```
$stmt->bind_result($app_id, $user_id, $app_name, $app_desc,$api_key);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<form class="appFragmentForm" id="'.$app_id.'" action="appDetails.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"><div class="thumbnail">
                               <img class="img-rounded appIcon" src="img/icon_app_placeholder.png">
                  <div class="caption text-center">
                    <h3>'.$app_name.'</h3>
                    <p>'.$app_desc.'</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger appDeatilsButton" id="'.$app_id.'" name="appDeleteButton" role="button">Delete App</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default appDeatilsButton" id="'.$app_id.'" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </form>'; 
}
}
```

Javascript function:

```
$(".appDeatilsButton").click(function (event) { 
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "appDetails.php",
  data: { ID: this.id}
 })
  .done(function( msg ) {
       window.location(appDetails.php);
   });
 });
```

appDetails.php

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();     
$appID = $_POST["appID"];  
echo '<script language="javascript">alert('.$appID.')</script>';    
?>
```

I know I am completely wrong, please help me in doing this in a eaiser way. FYI I am a mobile developer with little insight on web programming so web experts please excuse my newbie language.

Comment: Don't mix PHP and HTML code, please...

Comment: Please what? @TomaszKowalczyk I am trying to construct html dynamically via PHP.

Comment: Just replace your hyperlink (that's presumably styled to resemble a button) with an actual submit button!

Comment: @satheeshwaran he meant that, as we are in 2014, you should use a proper templating system, that would prevent you from messing between logic and presentation.

Comment: `$('.appDeatilsButton').on('click', function(event) {` .. btw you miss-spelled details

Comment: @satheeshwaran Then compute necessary data in PHP and then pass them to the proper view renderer. Don't do that in one place, it is a Separation of Concerns violation and something that will definitely bite you in the long run.

Comment: The problem here lies in the fact you should tell in your JS you wanna submit your form, which you dont. Also, you are not preventing the button's default action, which makes it act like a clickable without real purpose, so give it a       `event.preventDefault();` I would replace the `anchor` with a submit button and style that appropiatly, so it will function as a submit, which makes it much easier to work with.

Comment: @Dorvalla Thanks but I am creating so many forms but how will I know a button was clicked in that particular form.

Comment: Why you are using ajax? Simply redirect to your desired page when you done processing on server-side on submit button.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I want to pass data, can we POST a form to a PHP file without any <input> elements in it?

Comment: Have you tried hidden fields for it?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Just now did it dude, JINX!!!

Comment: So how you done it? used hidden fields?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Yes man I know a little bit of HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Put `this.form.submit();` instead of `window.location(appDetails.php);` in your JavaScript event handler (your javascript function).
And check errors in your code.
in the **first** code you posted on **9th** line you give `appDeatilsButton` (maybe *appDe**ta**ilsButton*...I don't know if it is a mis-spell) class to the "*Delete*" button.. the event handler `$(".appDeatilsButton").click()` runs the script whenever an element with class `appDeatilsButton` is clicked and it submits the form even if "*Delete*" button is clicked.

Comment: I tried it but getting error, Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined.